# Парковка ядер процессора

Tags: windows, cpu

В Интернете довольно популярная тема - как ОТКЛЮЧИТЬ парковку ядер (решение через реестр обычно). А у меня стоит обратная задача: можно ли запарковать ядра ПРИНУДИТЕЛЬНО и без перезагрузки операционной системы?

Update: [Вот](https://bitsum.com/parkcontrol/) скачал программу и у меня при "игре" ползунками это вроде получилось, но как это сделать самому программно?

Comment: Если ядер "не хватает" всёравно идёт програмная эмуляция нитей. У процессора есть аппаратная поддержка нитей -  Task-шлюзы. Думаю вам нужно почитать спецификацию процессора. Как простейшую реализацию - у каждого Task-шлюза есть AnifyMask, если сбросить у всех масок Один *бит* - ядро этого *бита* использоваться не будет. А вот общая маска  для всех Task скорее всего хранится в ядре винды, и доступна на уровне драйвера. Возможно это можно найти дизассемблированием ядра win, или "недокументироваными" ф-циями ядра win. Всёравно с уровня приложения вам управлять процессором win не позволит.

Comment: Какая у вас задача, ограничить к-во ядер работы приложения, или всей системы? Если одного приложения - вам сюда http://remontka.pro/select-cpu-affinity/ если "своё" приложение то SetThreadAffinityMask https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Так же можно загрузить "чужое" приложение через CreateProcess, и задать его нитям через SetProcessAffinityMask к-во разрешённых ядер.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Из комментария пользователя [@nick_n_a](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/17974/nick-n-a):*

Если ядер «не хватает», всё равно идёт программная эмуляция нитей.

Но у процессора также есть аппаратная поддержка нитей — Task-шлюзы. Думаю вам нужно почитать спецификацию процессора. Простейшая реализация — у каждого Task-шлюза есть *AnifyMask*, если сбросить у всех масок один бит, то ядро, соответствующее этому биту использоваться не будет. А вот общая маска для всех Task скорее всего хранится в ядре Windows и доступна на уровне драйвера. Возможно это можно найти дизассемблированием ядра, или его недокументироваными функциями. Всё равно с уровня приложения вам управлять процессором никто не позволит.